# Getting Custom Posts with Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, query-posts, tax-query

I am trying to get the custom posts "**contact**" with the custom taxonomy "**abteilung**" for this post type. Everything i am trying is not working. Now i am stuck with the following. The problem is, that the query is getting all the custom posts, not only that with the specific taxonomy id **29**.

In the Backend everything is working. I can add taxonomy items to the custom posts and it is counting right the number of posts with the tax-items but however, my query is not working:

```
    $args= array(
        'post_type' => 'contact',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'abteilung',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => 29
            )
        )
    );

    $query= new WP_Query($args);

    if($query-> have_posts()):
        while($query-> have_posts()): $query-> the_post();
            the_title(); //Just an example for the loop
        endwhile;
    endif;
```

The custom posts and taxonomy i created like this:

```
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type('contact',
        array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Kontakte'),
        'singular_name' => __('Kontakt')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array('title'),
    )
    );

    register_taxonomy('abteilung', 'contact',
        array(
            'hierarchical'  => true,
            'label'         => __('Abteilung'),
            'query_var'     => true
        )
    );
}

add_action ('init', 'create_post_type');
```

Comment: The problem is in your query arguments, you're missing `'tax_query' => ` before the outer array containing the taxonomy arguments. See [`WP_Query` Taxonomy Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) for examples.

Comment: Oh yes thank you. I missed it totally in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your taxonomy Query is worng. please try something like that:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'contact',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'abteilung',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => '29',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: It works! :) I forgot totally forgot the " 'tax_query' => " before the array but generally i had a problem with missing commas. Thank you!